# How can I convert electric utilities into water utilities?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometric-network, toolbar

I have GIS information for transmission lines, substations, and power generation facilities. I was able to import it into ArcGIS easily and create a geometric network. However, I'd really like to have access to the Water Utilities Network toolbars which have powerful tools and reporting capabilities that are not available in the electricity world. Since electricity and water are strongly related (voltage = pressure, current = flow, etc) I'd like to represent the electricity network as a water network and use the toolbar. Is this possible? If not, is there another way to access the water utility network tools for electricity?

Comment: What "Water Utilities Network toolbars" are you referring to? Please share the link in your question.